# Reading a string from stdin in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, gcc, undefined-behavior

I wrote a simple program to read a string.

```
void main()
{
    char *str; /*didn't allocate memory*/
    scanf(" %s",str);
    printf("%s",str);
}
```

But it is causing a segmentation fault. Whereas the next one isn't.

```
void main()
{
    char *str;
    scanf(" %c",str);
    printf("%c\n",str);
}
```

Would someone mind to clarify how actually this works?

Comment: Local non-static variables have an *indeterminate* value. When you have such a variable that is a pointer, and you dereference it, you have *undefined behavior*. There is often no way of predicting what will happen.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I compiled and ran your second program. It crashed as well. Undefined behavior can manifest itself differently on different machine, operating system, and compiler combinations.

Comment: "Would someone mind to clarify how actually this works?" - *it doesn't*; it invokes *undefined behavior*. You were lulled into a soft idea of success because you're definition of "works" appears to be  that the program simply "doesn't crash". Malformed programs invoking undefined behavior could certainly do that (or not) and if you're *unlucky*, they can even *appear* to work. Could be worse. It could have "worked" for you and not your instructor, employer, or worst of all, customer.

Comment: `char *str;
    scanf(" %c",str);` is broken code too.

Comment: both examples contain undefined behavior.  Suggest doing what the code should be doing,  I.E. point the `str` pointer to some memory your program actually owns

Answer (score 0):

You string isn't allocated. which mean you are writing somewhere you didn't ask for.

however what you can do is:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
  char c;
  while (scanf("%c",&c) && c != '\n')
    printf("%c",c);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

It will read every characters you send in input until you press return.

Comment: `getchar` would be a lot more natural than `scanf`. If you use scanf, remember that it returns EOF, not 0, on eof, and EOF is a "true" value. Finally, this doesn't skip whitespace.

Comment: because it's not meant to skip whitespace. Why would you want to skip the spaces between the words ?

Comment: For whatever reasons they have. The OP uses a space as the first charcter of the `scanf` formats, and the action is precisely to skip whitespace, so your proposed code is not equivalent.

Comment: There is nothing in the question which say : "I want to remove whitespaces" it only ask how to read a string so you are wrong.